Need object 1 to stay on path like a lesh but match object 2's height

Hello! So I am trying to get cube 1 in the picture to stay on a fixed path constraint to activate another driver with the values between "0 and 1.00".
The problem that I am having is I also want to put a driver on cube 1 so that Cube 1 matches the z location (up and down) of cube 2 .
So far when I put the driver on cube 1 to match the z of cube 2 it pulls the the object below the 0 value on path or above the 1 value. I need the object to stay in between these values like a leash.
Thank you in advance

The easiest way to do it is using constraints:

If you want to use drivers, you can select the top control piont of the driver curve, Shift D, X, Enter, to duplicate and move the keyframe; repeat for the bottom one; select all, right click > Interpolation mode > Linear.

